# How can i change the background color of list item in list fragment when it is selected on with the contextual action mode

Tags: android

I would like the background to change to grey when the list item are selected with the contextual action mode.
I have used selector that set the grey color on the activation state, but it is unable to override the BackgroundColor attribute.
When there is no background set it works, but when there's a background it doesn't. How can i work this out.

I have a list item with a background that is dynamically set using the following code:

```
 switch (task.getPriority()){
                case Task.VERY_HIGH_PRIORITY:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_red));
                    break;

                case Task.HIGH_PRIORITY:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_orange));
                    break;

                case Task.NORMAL_PRIORITY:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sunshine_blue));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sunshine_dark_blue));
                    break;

                case Task.LOW_PRIORITY:
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_green));

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to reproduce your situation. I set each list item background according to its priority, and then set an on item click listener to the list view, the following codes work for me:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
    }
});
```

My full codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        PriorityAdapter adapter = new PriorityAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Task task1 = new Task();
        task1.name = "task 1";
        task1.priority = Task.Priority.HIGH_PRIORITY;
        adapter.add(task1);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            }
        });

    }

}
```

The model:

```
public class Task {
    String name;

    enum Priority {
        VERY_HIGH_PRIORITY,
        HIGH_PRIORITY,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY,
        LOW_PRIORITY,
    }

    Priority priority;
}
```

And the adapter:

```
public class PriorityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

    Context context;

    public PriorityAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        Task task = getItem(position);
        switch (task.priority){
            case VERY_HIGH_PRIORITY:
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                break;
            case HIGH_PRIORITY:
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                break;
            case NORMAL_PRIORITY:
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.sunshine_blue));
                break;
            case LOW_PRIORITY:
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                break;
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView.setText(task.name);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the the item background to change grey when I use the contextual action mode that is triggered with a long click on the list item,so that I can see the items that are being selected  not on every click

Answer (score 0):

The way I would solve this is to put a `selected` flag in the model for your list item.  When the item is selected, an event would update this flag on the model.  Then when setting the background color, test the selected flag as well as the task priority.

Another option might be to overlay the entire view with another transparent view that could get a certain color when the item is selected, along with an alpha value that would allow the the user to see the widgets in the list item.